# how can I hide link of my web service from the inspector of browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

Please I want to ask you about a doubt for me in Angularjs. Now I'm working on an application and I use $http in order to call my web service. The problem that if a client use the browser and inspect the page can read my link of my web service!!! Please can you told me what's the best solution that I've to use to hide the link of my webservice from the inspector?

Comment: You can't.  If you expect the user's computer to make a request to your server, the user can always see that request if they want to.  This shouldn't be a problem, why do you think it is?

Comment: @David: Thank you for your response, so it's not prblem if the user can copy and paste the link of my webservice in the browser ... ?

Comment: when you say webservice do you mean some sort of REST API?

Comment: @BerguigaMed.Amine: No, it's not a problem.  There's no difference between your JavaScript code making the request from the user's browser and the user manually making the request from their browser or from any other client.

Answer (score 0):

You have to accept that if you are returning code to a browser/user agent and you include the ability to make a request to your API then the code will be visible to the user if they choose to inspect it. You need to manage the impact of tampering with your API in your application code. It's not practical to expect to hide the activity of a user's browser from them.